# Load data from file into struct

Tags: c, struct, instantiation

I'm attempting to read data from a text file and save the data into variables within a struct. However the problem I am encountering is I don't know how to make a 'new instance' of a struct. Java is my first programming language and I'm thinking of the algorithm in terms of object orientation but I'm failing to see how to translate it into C. This is what I have at the moment:

```
if (file != NULL) {


    while(status != EOF){
        status = fscanf(file,"%d %d %d",&struct.var1 , &struct.var2 , &struct.var3);
    }

    fclose(file);

}
```

What I have been able to do up to now is define a single instance of my struct and then add the data do it, but as the while loop progresses the data gets overwritten so in the end the data saved into the struct is from the last line of the file.

If I was doing this in Java I would be able to create a new struct before every iteration of the loop and then pass the value into it, but since in C I can't simply create a new instance  of the struct I am not sure how to do this. Any ideas here would be very appreciated.

Comment: Well, you need some sort of data structure to hold a list of these structs. Do you know how many records there are ahead of time?

Comment: Yes I was thinking of this, an array of structs would probably do the trick. And I do know how many records there would be, but ideally I'm trying to create a program that can read through to the end of file and create structs regardless of the amount

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

1. Create an array of `struct`s and add data into those successively.
2. Use `malloc` to dynamically allocate memory and add data to the dynamically allocated `struct`s.  Of course, you will have to keep track of those through an array or list.

Comment: Assuming I already have an array to hold structs, how would I actually go about automatically instantiating a new struct? The idea is that my program reads through to the end of file and it creates as many structs as there are lines in the file

Comment: If you use `malloc()` don't forget to be a good boy and call `free()` when you've finished. Then you'll start to discover why people think automatic garbage collection is such great feature of Java!

Comment: You can create a linked list by modifying the `struct` and adding a `next` field.  Or, you can create a new node that has two fields: `struct` and `next`.  When you `malloc` a new `struct`, you can add its address to the `next` field of the last `struct`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `malloc()` function to allocate new memory. But you have to be careful to release all those memory blocks after you are done using them, else you will have to deal with memory leaks.

(struct your_struct)malloc(sizeof(your_struct));

Answer (score 0):

You could predeclare an array of structs if you know the size

```
#define STATUSMAX 2000;

...
struct StatusType statusList[STATUSMAX];
...
```

Alternatively, if the size, statusMax, is passed in from somewhere else

```
struct StatusType* statusList = malloc(sizeof(struct StatusType) * statusMax);
```

Another alternative is to create a singly or doubly linked list.  Unlike Java, you are back to basics in C - you have to know how a list works and how to implement it: not just assume that it is a container in a library.  I'll leave you to look that up - there are lots of examples on the net.  Whenever you read in a new value, allocate a new item into the list and read it in.